# Can people with low rep (<300) at leaste suggest tags without asking someone else to create them?

Tags: feature-request

I noticed that the tag which relates to my question isn't available and I can't create it coz of low rep. So like editing tag wikis, can we have suggesting tags so that we don't have to wait till we get required rep?

Sorry if this question seems out of tune as I'm new on meta.

Comment: What tag do you want to create?

Answer (score 5):

This is such a small issue, as the number or new tags being created on the site is so low as most topics are already covered in a tag. If you really want a tag to be created and don't want to bug anyone just simply put it at the bottom of your post

"Also tagged: [blah]"

Someone will edit that tag in or remove your line if it's not a "good" tag.

Comment: True. Nevertheless technically this is applicable to all SE sites. Just wanted to point it out.\

Comment: +1 for BLAH ;). It is better to have minimum number of tags, so that maintenance and subscription is easy

Comment: @ved2254 My answer applies to most SE sites :) if a tag is important enough it'll be obvious to users editing and reading the question and 95% of the time it'll just get tagged appropriately. Tags aren't the be all end all of the question, it's the content that matters. Tags are simply just a little metadata sugar.

Comment: I've done what Marco said before, said I don't have permission to add a tag xulrunner could someone add it to the question. It worked. Also went to the chat rooms to ping someone who wouldn't mind.